# Got problems downloading updates in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: updates, package-management, system

I got an error icon above my menu bar. When I click on it I get three options with some details. It says

```
An error occurred please run package manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in terminal to see what's wrong.
The error message was: 'Error:brokencount>0'.
This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies"
```

I tried `apt-get` in terminal, with commands and options it says

```
See the apt-get(8), sources.list(5) and apt.conf(5) manual pages for more information and options. This APT has Super Cow Powers.
```

When I tried to update my system it failed to update and showed this error message:

```
The package is broken

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
steam-launcher: Depends: curl but it is not installed
                Depends: jockey-common but it is not installed
                Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is installed
```

Answer (score 0):

**sudo apt-get install steam-launcher**
This command should install steam-launcher and the dependencies that needs.
If you continues with problem maybe you can try using
**sudo apt-get install -f steam-launcher**

Comment: by trying this command
sudo apt-get install steam-launcher
I got this error
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam-launcher

Answer (score 0):

Try in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

It should update package list, remove any unnecessary packages, fix broken packages and manage dependencies.

Comment: if you try and have an error, can you let me know ?

Comment: I tried these commands sir but when I try last command it shows me this

Comment: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/shotwell/shotwell_0.13.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: it seems you have many problems with packages. you should try changing the mirror you are using to main, and update again.